# Terraform depends on attribute accept values defined from case statements?

Tags: terraform

It is clear enough based on Terraform documentation that you can have case statements for an attribute value. For example:

```
count = "${var.example == true ? 1 : 0}"
```

My question is, for the `depends_on` parameter can you apply the same logic?

For example:

```
depends_on = [$var.example == true ?resource.name : another.resource.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21418#issuecomment-495818852

herein you may add your case statement inside the null_resource block and try it

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation isn't supported inside `depends_on` at this time. For example if you tried to do this:

```
depends_on = ["${var.test}"]
```

You get an error:

```
depends on value cannot contain interpolations: ${var.test}
```

The conditional you are using is a form of interpolation, therefore it's also invalid in this case.